# How to fix the Not a number value?

Tags: javascript, class, object, methods

Using this script i m facing this error `Not a number value` that i don t understand,

How can I fix this ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>The Cube</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        var cube = function(side) {

        this._side = side;

        this.volume = function() {
            var vol = Math.pow(this.side, 3);
            return vol;
        };

        this.surface = function() {
            var totalLength = 12 * this.side;
            return totalLength;
        };

    };

    var firstCube = new cube(2);
    document.write("Volumul " + firstCube.volume() + "<br>");
    document.write("Total length " + firstCube.surface());
   </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw, the surface of a cube is `Math.pow(side, 2) * 6`, just saying.

Answer (score 2):

You assign the value of `side` to `this._side`. Therefore you can access it as `side` inside of the function and as `this._side` inside of every method (as your methods are inside the function too, both will work). But `this.side` does not exist, it is not defined, and multiplying it results in Not a Number.

---

How I would write that:

```
 class Cube {
  constructor(side) { this.side = side; }
  get volume() { return Math.pow(this.side, 3); }
  get surface() { return 12 * this.side; }
}

const cube = new Cube(3);
console.log(cube.volume, cube.surface);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help .